# Apollo Federated Gateway returns an error when trying to use a .NET Core GraphQL federated subgraph

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

I am trying to learn **Apollo Federation**, so I started by looking at their sample (https://github.com/apollographql/federation-demo). This sample repository works great, and I can add a new service as a subgraph in Node.js.

I want to add a new service as a subgraph in .NET Core as well to extend the `User` type defined in the sample project. I did so by created a new service using [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet).

My schema is defined as the following:

```
extend type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID! @external
    phone: String
}
```

---

The GraphQL Playground seems to work properly, but when I try to include the service in my gateway, I get the following error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Couldn't load service definitions for "user-service" at http://localhost:5000/graphql: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is caused by the fact that the graphql-dotnet server NuGet package (currently 5.0.2) does not generate the proper SDL if you do not extend the query type. The service starts up properly and I can navigate to the UI Playground.

**Query:**

```
query {
  _service {
    sdl
  }
}
```

**Result (json):**

```
{
  "data": {
    "_service": {
      "sdl": "type Query {\r\n\r\n}\r\n\r\nextend type User @key(fields: \"id\") {\r\n  id: ID! @external\r\n  phone: String\r\n}\r\n"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

---

Note that graphql-dotnet generates an empty `type Query {\r\n\r\n}` section in the SDL, which should not be there because I did not extend the query type in my schema. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/2563) with the graphql-dotnet github project.

A work-around could be to extend the query type with new functionality, at least until the issue is resolved.